# Creating a vertical HTML/CSS menu and I want to remove <li> top padding (displays in both FF and IE)

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm creating a navigation menu using HTML and CSS for a library OPAC. There seems to be unwanted top padding in each li item which results in a persistent gap between items in the menu. This is visible both in the latest firefox and in IE 9.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="menu_div">
<ul>
<li id="mainnav">Find Information</li>
<li><a href="#">Catalogue</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Databases</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Guides</a></li?
</ul>
</div>
```

My CSS reads:

```
.menu_div ul
{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
padding-top: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
color:#FFF;
list-style:none;
text-indent:10px;
color:#000000;
}

.menu_div ul li
{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
padding-top: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
list-style:none;
background:#CCC;
line-height:20px;
border-bottom:1px solid #333;
color:#000000;
}

.menu_div ul li a
{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
padding-top: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
display:block;
color:#000000;
}

.menu_div ul li a:hover
{
background: #293895;
color:#FFFFFF;
}

.menu_div ul li#mainnav
{
background:#293895;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

The screenshot shows the 'gap' I am talking about, in between the two items (cursor hovering over the 2nd item):

http://postimage.org/image/5dxn7j56z/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely caused by a line height being set, this is generally inherited from something in the code that surrounds your list. Try appending `line-height: 1em;` to the CSS of each element in order to remove that extra spacing.

Edit: If you view the JSfiddle located here: http://jsfiddle.net/pCAfk/ there is no spacing since there has been no inherited line-height.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately that doesn't help at all. It 'compresses' the entire nav, but still does not remove the gap. I took a screenshot after applying the line height: http://postimage.org/image/gpiup3vd5/

Comment: Have you used any browser dev tools to see if it it is in fact padding or maybe margin? There may be another more specific CSS rule overriding the one you want.

Comment: Thanks, I've just had a look using dev tools. There doesn't appear to be anything which would add padding or extra spacing in any way. Firefox Dev tools:   rgb(0, 0, 0)
display: block
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif
font-size: 13px
line-height: 20px
list-style-image: none
list-style-position: outside
list-style-type: none
text-decoration: none
text-indent: 10px
-moz-text-blink: none
-moz-text-decoration-color: rgb(0, 0, 0)
-moz-text-decoration-line: none
-moz-text-decoration-style: solid. Same in firebug. Dev tools also confirm margin, border, and padding are all 0. Thoughts?